# web view loading in simulator but not loading in my device (ios 8)

Tags: ios, webview, device

web view is loading fine in simulator but not in my device having ios 8 version ..here is my code

```
[super viewDidLoad];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BGColor.jpg"]];
self.navigationItem.title = textType;

//[self createHUD];
linkWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
if(self.navigationController.viewControllers)
  linkWebView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, phoneType-105);
else
   linkWebView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0+60, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, phoneType-63);
linkWebView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:linkWebView];

indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
indicator.frame = CGRectMake(([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/2)-18, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height/2)-45-15, 40, 40);
indicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
[indicator startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:indicator];

urlStr = appDelegate.selectedURL;

if ([textType isEqualToString:@"About"])
{
    [linkWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/index/about.html?jsonFooter=hideHeaderFooter",urlStr]]]];//about.html

}
```

its working fine in other device having ios 6 version..why it is not working in my device? thanks in advance

Comment: may be your condition is not statisfied

Comment: @avijit nagare I am not using http but i dont think that should make any difference as it is displaying in other device(ios 6) & simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is "textType" definitely going to be "About", with uppercase "A"? Try sticking a break point or NSLog() inside the condition.  Also, try separating out the loadRequest parameters in to variables so you can check each part is populated correctly.

Comment: [linkWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/index/about.html?jsonFooter=hideHeaderFooter",urlStr]]]]                                       [self.view addSubview:linkWebView];    by using this code issue seemed to be resolved..should we load request in web view before adding web view in View